# How to in insert new rows from one table to another based on date?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having two tables (table1 and table2). I have columns `Date, A, B, C` in table1 and columns `Date, D, E`  in table2. I need to transfer column D and E from table2 to table1 based on Date in both the tables.

I tried below code but getting 'multi-part identifier "table1.Date" could not be bound.' error

```
  INSERT INTO table1
SELECT D,E FROM table2
WHERE table2.Date = table1.Date


Table1 :
Date        A   B   C
1945-01-01  1   2   3
1945-02-01  1   2   4  
1945-03-01  5   6   7 

Table2 :
Date        D   E   
1945-02-01  8   2     
1945-03-01  5   6
```

Expected output:

```
Table1 :
Date        A   B   C  D      E
1945-01-01  1   2   3  Null   Null
1945-02-01  1   2   4  8      2
1945-03-01  5   6   7  5      6
```

Comment: Can you share your attempt at solving this yourself?

Comment: Please provide sample input and desired output table.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: `INSERT INTO table1 
select * from (SELECT D,E FROM table2, tabel1
WHERE table2.Date = table1.Date) t21`

Comment: If you named your column date, first you may have to properly name with `[Date]`. Second, your insert doesn't contain the num of values that Table1 has.

Comment: @IdontKnowEnglish that insert will never work.

Comment: What you want is incredibly simple. But it requires a little bit of effort from you. We can't see your screen and don't know what your table structures are. And it is not totally clear what you are trying to do. Give us those details and an answer will be shortly behind.

Comment: @SeanLange.. Oh.. Okay.. Thx....But I think it will work like as `update using join`

Comment: @IdontKnowEnglish - Not the way you have that coded. The select statement would need to work on its own and there is no reference to table1. Besides an insert means creating a new row but you are using an existing value in the table you are about to insert to.

Comment: Are you trying to permanently add those columns to table 1 or just in the output? And remember that an INSERT is used to generate new rows, an UPDATE is used to change values in an existing row.

Comment: Trying to permanently add columns to table1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to add those columns to Table1. Then you need to update the existing rows. Something like this should work.

```
alter table Table1
    add D int

alter table Table1
    add E int

GO

update t
set D = t2.D
    , E = t2.E
from Table2 t2
left join Table1 t on t.Date = t2.Date
```

Answer (score 0):

You are rather asking of how to `JOIN` tables, because you **can not add columns with insert statement**.

Having said that, you are looking for `LEFT JOIN` (well, if table on the left side of operator is `Table1`), try this:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 T1
LEFT JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.[Date] = T2.[Date]
```

If you want to have this as "table" and use it without `JOIN`s, then I recommend you getting familiar with views: [CREATE VIEW (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)